# Displaying Posts Depending on Number of Comments and Latest Comments?

Tags: comments, sort

I would like to be able to display a list of posts on a page depending on when and how many comments they've got.
Something similar to how it is here on stackexchange.

To be more specific, I want:

- A page with the most commented posts.
- A page with the most recently commented posts.
- A page with all the uncommented posts.

Help with this would be very appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: *@Patrik*: Where and how do you want to display them?  As sticky posts, in a sidebar widget, or other? More details will help us answer.

Comment: As a page with a list of blog posts. Just like a blog but instead of having the latest post show up first, the 2nd latest post after that etc, they are displayed depending on the conditions mentioned above. I hope you understand what I mean, english is not my primary language :)

Answer (score 2):

```
query_posts( array('orderby' => 'comment_count', 'order'=>'DESC') )
```

This should do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = WP_Query;

foreach ($query['posts'] as $post){
  $count = $post['comment_count'];
  while (is_set($comment_sort[$count]){
   $count--;
  }    
  $comment_sort[$count]=$post['ID'];
}

$sorted = ksort($comment_sort);
$sorted = array_reverse($sorted);
```

this should give you an array of post ID's in decending order of comment counts.

Answer (score 0):

@Patrik - I had a similar problem: In a WPMu installation, show the latest posts in post-order on the main blog.  The easiest solution for me was to create a new table that holds the data for new blog posts (new posts are inserted via a plugin), and query that table for the main page.  You can do the same, and just edit the SQL query to return based on most comments, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Posts with recent comments:

```
$comments = get_comments( array(
    'status' => 'approve',
    'number' => 10
) );

$include = array();

foreach ( $comments as $comment )
    $include[] = $comment->comment_post_ID;

query_posts( array(
    'post__in' => array_unique( $include )
) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Code snippet for displaying posts with most comments:

```
<?php 
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT comment_count, ID, post_title FROM $wpdb->posts ORDER BY comment_count DESC LIMIT 0 , 10"); // NUMBER OF POSTS
foreach ($result as $topten) {
    $postid = $topten->ID;
    $title = $topten->post_title;
    $commentcount = $topten->comment_count;
    if ($commentcount != 0) {
?>

<li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($postid); ?>"><?php echo $title ?></a></li>

<?php } } ?>
```